# Power BI / DAX show count of distinct values in column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'd like to expand the solution on [this page](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Count-of-values-in-a-column/m-p/1886337#M724504).

The original solution is given in Power query. But I'd like a DAX solution...

I've created a table from the fields *Source* and *Preparer*. If I want to see those sources where there is only one preparer what's is the best way to do it via DAX?
Like the Sources "MN", "RT" and "PO".

| Source | Preparer |
| --- | --- |
| AB | June |
| AB | Jane |
| MN | June |
| SS | Kim |
| SS | Lee |
| SS | Jim |
| RT | Kim |
| PO | June |
| PO | June |
| RT | Kim |

The outcome I'm looking for is like:

| Source | Preparer | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MN | June | 1 |
| RT | Kim | 1 |
| PO | June | 1 |

DAX that comes close looks like:

```
TableResult = 
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'Table'[Source],
        "Number", DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Preparer] )
    ),
    [Number] = 1
)
```

This gives the source and the number, but not the Preparer....
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
newMeasure = 
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table 1'[Preparer] ),
    FILTER (
        GROUPBY ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Source], 'Table 1'[Preparer] ),
        CALCULATE (
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table 1'[Preparer] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table 1', 'Table 1'[Source] )
        ) = 1
    )
)
```

[image: Solution]